# Razor View Engine Syntax

Tags: razor

I have model that represents a hierarchy of web pages. I want to create a left menu by recursively climbing the tree and rending out HTML, this is my code:

```
@{var parent = Model}

<!-- create stating html for ancestors up the tree -->

@do{
    <ul>
        <li><a href='@parent.Url'>@parent.MenuTitle</a>

        @{parent  = parent.Parent}

}while(parent != null)

<!-- create children of the current page -->

<ul>
    @foreach (var child in Model.Children)
    {
        <li><a href="@child.Url">@child.MenuTitle</a></li>
    }
</ul>   

<!-- close stating html for ancestors up the tree -->

@{parent = Model}

@do{
        </li>
    </ul>

   @{parent  = parent.Parent}

}while(parent != null)
```

However Razor intellisense in Visual Studio does not like this kind of disconnected HTML, i.e. opening HTML element in one area and closing in the other. Is there a way around this? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is but it looks ugly. You can cheat it by adding `@:` before the tag in which case the Razor parser will consider it as literal:

```
@:<ul>
```

and:

```
@:<li>
<a href='@parent.Url'>@parent.MenuTitle</a>
```

etc...

Of course the correct way to do this would be to adapt your view model in such a way that the heavy lifting is done on the server and so that inside your view all you need is to loop through the values and generate the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio intellisense has no way of knowing if the opening and closing tags in two different loops really match, so it's totally normal for it topoint it to you. If you know what you're doing and are sure your code will generate matching tags, you can just ignore the intellisense's complain: it should not prevent your razor page from working.